Saving several output of an algorithm in a list for former processings in QGIS with Python
I am working on a specific buffer tool for my job. I try to get 3 temporary buffer which schould be merged, saved and load in the project. But I cannot manage to save the three temporary results in a list for the merging process. Only one is saved in the list out[].
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import QgsFileWidget
import processing

import os

pluginPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
uiPath = os.path.join(pluginPath, 'new_Puffer.ui')
#WIDGET und BASE sind Variablen-Namen/Klassen
#WIDGET beinhaltet die Einstellungen der Maske (setupUI)
#BASE enthält die Grundlagen der Methoden
WIDGET, BASE = uic.loadUiType(uiPath)
#An Projekt vererben
class CreateUR(BASE, WIDGET):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
    
#Maske befüllen
    self.fillGUI()
 #Knöpfe mit Methoden verknüpfen
    self.pb_Abb.clicked.connect(self.close)
    self.pb_OK.clicked.connect(self.UR_Puff)

def fillGUI(self):
    lyrDict = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
    for lyr in lyrDict.values():
        self.cb_lyr.addItem(lyr.name(),lyr)
    

    
def UR_Puff (self):  
    UR = [1000,3000,5000]
    inPut = self.cb_lyr.currentData()
    check = self.cb_Add.isChecked()
    Extra = self.sb_Add.value()
    Dis = self.chb_Dis.isChecked()
    path = self.btn_ext.filePath()
    out = []
    if check == True:
        for ur in UR:                
            params = {'INPUT': inPut,
                'DISTANCE': ur+Extra,
                'SEGMENTS': 50,
                'DISSOLVE': Dis,
                'OUTPUT': 'memory:' + f'{inPut.name()}_UR{ur+Extra}'}
            out.append(processing.run('native:buffer', params))#['OUTPUT']
            print(out) #Test
            out1 = out[0]
            out2 = out[1]
            out3 = out[2]
            path2 = path + '/'+ f'{inPut.name()}_UR_Abfrage'
            res = processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS': [out1, out2, out3], 'OUTPUT': path2})
            resLyr = res['OUTPUT']
            Symbol = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'outline_style': 'solid', 'outline_color': 'black', 'color': 'transparent', 'outline_width': '0.5'})
            resLyr.renderer().setSymbol(Symbol)
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(resLyr)
            self.close()
    else: # original code that creates and loads the three different buffers successfully
        for ur in UR:
            params = {'INPUT': inPut,
                'DISTANCE': ur,
                'SEGMENTS': 50,
                'DISSOLVE': Dis,
                'OUTPUT': 'memory:' + f'{inPut.name()}_UR{ur}'}
            res = processing.run('native:buffer', params)#['OUTPUT']
            resLyr = res['OUTPUT']    
            Symbol = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'outline_style': 'solid', 'outline_color': 'black', 'color': 'transparent', 'outline_width': '0.5'})
            resLyr.renderer().setSymbol(Symbol)
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(resLyr)
            self.close()

